# active/connected rostopics to terminal list or file

Tags: ros, rosnode, rqt-graph, rostopic, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to get the active or connected (i.e. excluding leaf topics) ROS topics as a list to the terminal or a text file? The topics can limited to only the active topics from `rqt_graph` but are there any methods the `rostopic` or `rosnode` (or combination of the two) commands can generate a list? Can `rqt_graph` save the active topics or log them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253398/active/connected-rostopics-to-terminal-list-or-file/) by [roboticom314](https://answers.ros.org/users/26759/roboticom314/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2017-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
rostopic list -s
```

gives a list of subscribed, active topics. To save the list,

```
rostopic list -s > activeTopics.txt
```

Will save the list in your current directory. I don't see an easy way to do the same with nodes, though.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roboticom314](https://answers.ros.org/users/26759/roboticom314/) on 2017-01-31**:
That works thanks. I always had assumed that the `-s` option was for all subscriptions regardless of connection state. I verified using `rqt_graph` that it's only the connected topics.